# Is there any way to buy Dive items from the normal shops?

Tags: disgaea-5

I know you get Dive's and Mr. Gency Exit's from beating bosses every 10 floors and they are available in the Item Worlder's shop in her Mystery Room but is there any point where you will be able to purchase them straight from the Pocket Netherworld Shops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot purchase either of the items from the Pocket Netherworld Shops, but they can be made through the Alchemist Shop in PostGame.

Pocket Netherworld Shops are really just meant to be the bare minimum items.  In this case, you have to beat the game first to be able to make them, and then each item (up to 3) will progress depending on how many stages/floors you clear.

Edit: Changed the post to include more information, without all the extra information.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. I figured if at all they would be the VERY last thing added to the shops anyway. I had just never gotten far enough to check

Comment: Yeah, the Diver items are new, but it makes sense considering skipping floors no longer gives levels and you can go past floor 100.